# jqGrid sorts only some columns and not all

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

I'm making a table that fetches game match results.
The problem is that when I try to sort the match results (subgrids), only num and team column can be sortable, and other columns are not sortable. Am I missing something? Please help.

http://darkencraft.woobi.co.kr/DotA2Login/WinTablev2.php

Below is the subgrids that I'm having trouble sorting with:

```
jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
url:"get_match_detail.php?q=1&match_id="+(jQuery("#match_list").getRowData(row_id))['match'],
datatype: "json",
colNames: ['Num','Team','Name','Steam ID #', 'Hero', 'Hero', 'Image', 'Kills','Deaths','Assists','Creep Kills','Denies','Gold-per-Minute','Experience-per-Minute'],
colModel: [
{name:"num",index:"num",width:30,key:true},
{name:"team",index:"team",width:30},
{name:"name",index:"match_id",width:80},
{name:"steamid",index:"win",width:150,align:"right"},
{name:"hero_en",index:"match_id",width:80},
.....more columns
{name:"epm",index:"match_id",width:80}
],
sortname: 'num',      
pager: pager_id,
rowNum:20,
height: '100%',  
sortable: true,
loadonce: true,
sortorder: "asc",});
```

Comment: Looks like you got it to work?

Comment: I eventually got it to work. It was stupid mistake of mine, which I had several index with same name, "match_id" and this caused the sorting issue.